# Alert is displaying before the page reloads

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to redirect pages and then display an alert message however the page does not get redirected until after the alert message is acknowledged. Is there something that I need to do to force the redirect?

```
function OnTimeoutReached() {
            logoutUser = true;
            window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Logoff","Account")";
            alert("You have been automatically logged off from the system.");
        }
```

Comment: That looks like malformed code to me, try using single quotes inside the duoble quotes around logoff and account?

Comment: The action from setting location.href is non-blocking, its not going to block the rest of the script from executing. Even if it did this would not work as when the page reloads you've lost what code was executing, it doesn't carry over.

Comment: @Patrick, yes that's what I was thinking. You'd need the message to be on the page that you redirect to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly speaking, I don't know what framework is used by `window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Logoff","Account")";`. But I know the basic of browser behavior.

You can type the following line:

```
window.location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com"
```

into the devTool console, and hit enter.

See what happens? The tab loads another page and **drops the current running context**.

There is no way to write an `alert` statement and hope it would run in another page *directly*. And of course alert will run soon after the `href` assignment, it's an synchronous operation.

There are plenty of way to communicate between pages.

- **local**storage
- query params
- `window.title`
- ...

But the first thing i think you should learn about is how the browser and pages work.

Hope I've cleared things out.

Comment: The bit you're confused about is just `asp.net mvc` and all it does is produce a URI string.

Answer (score 0):

`alert()`s are blocking. They stop all execution until the user responds to them.

It is not possible to use client side code to make an alert appear on *the next page*.

Only code on the next page can make the alert appear.

You could use (for example) a query string parameter on the URL which you could read with code on the next page and then alert in response to that.